# Why does WordPress append numbers to page slugs sometimes? How to reliably style based on page

Tags: theme-development

Why isit that WordPress sometimes add a number to my slug even if I explicitly set it. Like if I set slug to be 'about' I get 'about-2'. I want the slug to be correct so I can style using CSS easily. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress appends a number to your slug when the database already contains a duplicate slug.  It will append the number even if the duplicate post or page has been moved to the trash.

The URL Routing system is one of the weaknesses of WordPress.  **[Mike Schinkel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel)** made a very good proposal to **[evolve the re write engine](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12935)** on trac but the ticket was closed as "wont fix"

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the trash ... emptied it and it works. I knew it was something to do with duplication, but I dont see a page with that slug ... just forgot trash ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

When WordPress appends numbers to the slug it usually means that you allready have a page or post with that slug.

But if you can style based on the slug you can always style based on the page or post ID.

Comment: But post id may change if I migrate the theme for use in another server